# How do I auto-populate city and state based on zip-code with JavaScript and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, zipcode, auto-populate

I am creating form that requires address input. If user inputs zip-code first how do I make it auto-populate the city and state based off the zip-code? The city would auto-populate into a text input and the state would auto-select from a drop-down menu. I have every state listed in my code but for my example I only included a few to keep it shorter. Currently I have this:

```
<div>
  <fieldset>
     <legend>Golfer 1:</legend>
     <label for="name">Name:</label>
     <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
     <label for="address">Street Address:</label>
     <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
     <label for="city">City:</label>
     <input type="text" id="city" name="city"><br>
     <label for="state">State:</label>
     <select id="state" name="state">
       <option disabled selected value> -- select a state -- </option>
       <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
       <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
       <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
       <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
     </select>
     <label for="zipcode">Zip Code:</label>
     <input type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode"><br>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I have a url to send the zip-code to where zip-code = xxxxx and the url returns STATE_city,city,city. How do I send the zip-code to the url and then have it auto-populate this data into the state input and give a city dropdown in the current city input with the city options.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'm afraid this is too broad to be meaningfully answered here.  At the very least you're going to need to have some data source or service which can provide you with this information.  Then you'll need to write code which uses the zipcode value to fetch this information from that data source and populate the other elements with the results.  If the plan is to do this in JavaScript then you'll need to get started on writing some JavaScript code.  If you encounter a specific problem in your attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it using a javascript call to Google Geocode API

```
window.findAddressFromZip = function(zipcode) {
  var city, state, zip;
  zip = zipcode.value;
  city = '';
  state = '';
  if (zip.length === 5) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + zip + "?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      success: (function(_this) {
        return function(data) {
          if (data["status"] === "OK") {
            $('input#user_account_attributes_address_attributes_city').val(data["results"][0]["address_components"][1]["long_name"]);
            return $('select#user_account_attributes_address_attributes_state').val(data["results"][0]["address_components"][4]["long_name"]);
          }
        };
      })(this)
    });
  }
};
```

Or, could you [try some other API](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/top-10-apis-zip-codes/brief/2020/07/26) to get data from U.S. Postal Service using a zip code.